# Migration a Question to another StackExchange

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

It is the first time I enable the review option. I try to flag a question as it would fit better to another stack exchange, but the only option I have is the meta.opendata. How I suppose to choose the right Stack Exchange to flag the question if I don't have all the options?

Thank you

**Edit:** The problem is still out there. I cannot flag a question that fit better to another SE, except meta.opendata.se

**Edit 2:** The problem still exists three years later (2016-08-16). [This Question Seems to Belong on Data Science SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) but flagging -> close -> migrate to site --- still only shows meta.opendata.stackexchange.com as its only option

Comment: try looking under the 'close' -> 'off topic' ... I just saw it there when closing another question.  (but I'm scared to check what that one does for fear of accidentally closing something by accident)

Comment: Someone else did it and I cannot find the question now. But I will try it in the next "off topic" review I will see :)

Comment: @Joe I tried to flag this question http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1263/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-fixml-file-in-python to move it on stackoverflow. I follow this pattern -> flag -> it should be closed for another reason -> off topic because -> this question belongs to another stack exchange. And I have only meta.opendata as an option. Is there any way to forward it to technical support so we can have an official answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, [migration paths are limited](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/new-question-migration-paths/).  Moderators can migrate to any site, but the community can only vote to close a question as "off-topic" and leave a comment or a flag indicating which site it belongs on.

**However**, even when a question is clearly ontopic on some other site, we generally [discourage migration](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/).  That's because the person who asked thought their question belongs *here*.  If there's some way to help them get their question ontopic, do that first.  In the case linked in the comments, the question would probably have fared poorly on Stack Overflow.  It might be they would have gotten a better answer here with a little bit of help.